# How to get InnerText of XML Document?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using XML Reader to read an XML document that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<profile username="666">
  <purchases>
    <purchase id="221"> 
      <price>5599</price>
      <quantity>22<quantity>
      <description>This is some placeholder text</description>
    </purchase>
  <purchases>
    <purchase id="621"> 
      <price>234</price>
      <quantity>5<quantity>
      <description>This is some placeholder text</description>
    </purchase>
  </purchases>
</profile>
```

I want to get the elements purchase id, price, quantity, and description, then add them to my profile method.

Here is my current code

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(doc))
{
    while(reader.ReadToFollowing("purchase"))
    {
        var id = reader.GetAttribute("id");

        while(reader.ReadToFollowing("price"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how can I fetch the inner contents of price, quantity etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attribute etc you just have to use `VALUE`

```
while(reader.ReadToFollowing("price"))
{
  Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML.
Below example will get all price nodes on the XML

```
var xml = XElement.Load(YourXMLDocumentPath);

var allPriceNodes = xml.Elements()
    .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "purchases")
    .Elements()
    .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "purchase")
    .Elements()
    .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "price");
```

also you can get a specific value like the first price tag value you can add .FirstOrDefault().Value;

Comment: Could I use that to collect the id number as well?

Comment: Yes, sure here is an example that gets all purchase tags Id attribute values  
  .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "purchase")
  .Select(t=>t.Attributes("id"));

Comment: One last question, how could I erase this data? How would the var be formatted?

Comment: I need to insert every element individually

Comment: sorry for being late, actually I didn't understand what exactly you need, but to do something individually just loop on the result like foreach(var node in allPriceNodes)